# Traversing a directory and it's subdirectories but having an IF NOT condition specified also in batch file

Tags: if-statement, recursion, batch-file, traversal

I have a problem that should be easy enough to solve (I think); I'm just having trouble with it due to inexperience with batch commands and using them correctly.

I have a directory that has many subfolders. Each of these sufolders contains .sql files that need to be executed. However, one of the subfolders requires not to have it's file's executed at all, but must remain in the folder (i.e. I do not have the authority to just delete this folder and work away with the others).

Here's what I have at the moment, but what I'm not sure about is the IF NOT statement; how should this be written correctly?

```
for /r %ROOT% %%b in (.) do (
if  NOT ==CertainFolder(
sqlcmd -S %SERVER% -d %DATABASE% -i %%~nb -b 
)
```

Any help at all would be appreciated; As I said, I'm a novice at this kind of thing and all my searches have thrown up unhelpful stuff; the for, I feel, is making it to specific which is why I'm at a loss parameter wise for the if not!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use DIR /B /S to list all SQL files, pipe result to FINDSTR to filter out paths that contain the CertainFolder. Process the results with FOR /F, running each file through SQLCMD.

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b /a-d /s "%ROOT%\*.sql" ^| findstr /livc:"\\CertainFolder\\"'
) do sqlcmd -S %SERVER% -d %DATABASE% -i "%%F" -b
```

As written, this solution will also exclude files in subfolders of CertainFolder. For example, `ROOT\CertainFolder\subFolder\name.sql` would be excluded

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for /r "%ROOT%" %%b in (.) do if  NOT "%%~b"=="CertainFolder" sqlcmd -S %SERVER% -d %DATABASE% -i "%%~nb" -b
```

or this:

```
for /r "%ROOT%" %%b in (.) do if  NOT "%%~nb"=="CertainFolder" sqlcmd -S %SERVER% -d %DATABASE% -i "%%~nb" -b
```

Comment: CertainFolder is one particular folder node within an entire file path. You are attempting to compare it to a an entire path, or else a file name without extension. That won't work!

Comment: The `for /?`  help text told me, `(.)`  lists the folder tree.

Comment: Oops, sorry you are correct. Without a wildcard, it reports the folder path. Using that construct, one additional FOR loop is needed to get the individual SQL file names to exececute - that critical step is missing from the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /R %ROOT% %%b IN (.) DO IF /I NOT "%%~nxb" == "CertainFolder" SQLCMD -S %SERVER% -d %DATABASE% -i "%%~nxb" -b
```

just ensure `CertainFolder` is quoted.
You may recover nesting, but is not needed here.

EDIT: Make also sure %ROOT% is quoted or use "%ROOT%".

Comment: This precise thing did not work; however, I changed tack a little and wondered if maybe you could help me. I was thinking of instead, once I'm looping through everything, if I get the parent folder and it's NOT that certain folder, then do everything; like so:

    for /r . %%g in (*.sql) do (
    if not %~pg=="CertainFolder"
 sqlcmd -S %SERVER% -d %DATABASE% -i %%~ng.sql -b)

Once again though, I'm sure that my syntax is off. Would this be a suitable alternative approach?

Comment: Answer approach should work. Give me examples of `CertainFolder` and `%ROOT%`.

Comment: %ROOT% would be something like C:/Companies, and certain folder would be in there and would be say Google, Microsoft, Apple etc. Google would be a folder, and inside it would have a bunch of sql files and that's it. So the entire file path of statement.sql would be C:/Companies/Google/statement.sql.